# Ensure only one instance of an event handler is running at a time

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have an application that interacts with HID devices, on slower machines it seems to get hung up on itself when I subscribe to the onReport event raised when a HID report is received and I suspect it is because it is launching a new instance of the event handler possibly before the previous one has finished its tasks.

Is there a way to ensure that reports are ignored until the previous event handler has finished its tasks? I was thinking a static variable that the handler could set as its last action but id like to fins something built into .net if it exists.

Comment: Well what thread is the event being handled on? Without knowing what's raising the event, or basically more context, then it's hard to know the best solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet Each HID device has its own thread and the event is handled in the devices thread

Comment: Right - so the event handlers for different HIDs are interacting with each other? Can you just avoid that? It would be better not to block all HID event handlers just because one hasn't finished...

Comment: @JonSkeet They are not interacting with each other, Its just at times the reports come in faster than the application can handle them and I think it is cause multiple instance of the event handler for a single device to be active at once.

Comment: No, that can't be the case if it's as you say: "the event is handled in the devices thread" - a thread can only be doing one thing at a time, unless you're deliberately introducing reentrancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads synchronisations mechanisms to make sure only onle thread can run a particular piece of code at the same time. Have a search in Googles for threads synchronization.

The most simple solutions you could consider is to use a lock mechanism:

```
lock (lockObject)
{
    // The code that you put here can be run only on one thread at the same time...
    // ...
}
```

You can also introduce some fields that will mark if particular parts of code have / haven't been executed already.